# Parameter length does not match remote action parameters

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

Having a page that uses AngularJS with Remote Actions to manipulate data, I'm facing an issue while trying to save the data to the server.

I have a method on the controller that receives two `String` parameters that are two lists of objects serialized as JSON. The method's signature looks like this:

```
global static void save(String receipts, String items)
```

Of course, it has the `@RemoteAction` annotation.

My issue is one the page's JavaScript. I try to pass the two parameters on a list, but Salesforce keeps giving me an error on the console:

> Visualforce Remoting: Parameter length does not match remote action
>   parameters: expected 2 parameters, got

I'm trying to pass a list with the two serialized lists as the `invokeAction` function parameter:

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
  '{!$RemoteAction.ReceiveItemsController.save}',
    [JSON.stringify(list_a), JSON.stringify(list_b)],
    function (result, event) {
      if (event.statusCode == 200) {
        // yay!
      }
    }, { escape : false })
```

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_invoking.htm) specifies the call like this:

```
[***namespace***.]controller.method(
    [parameters...,]
    callbackFunction,
    [configuration]
);
```

And specifies that `parameters` is...

> A comma-separated list of parameters that your method takes.

So what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[` (square brackets) are not needed to enclose parameters.

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
  '{!$RemoteAction.ReceiveItemsController.save}',
    JSON.stringify(list_a), JSON.stringify(list_b),
    function (result, event) {
      if (event.statusCode == 200) {
        // yay!
      }
    }, { escape : false })
```

Comment: The part "list of parameters" can get really confusing. I thought it was literally a list of parameters, not the parameters after the method and before the callback function. Thank you Ashwani!